# Is there a way to rename table column with a greek symbol in gt package?

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse, gt

So this is my code and i would like to create a table with the package gt and change the column name "Estimate" by the greek symbol beta

```
library(gt)
gt() %>% cols_label(
    "Estimate" = expression(beta)
)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options but you can't use plotmath expressions afaik. You can use the unicode encoding, paste it directly as a character, or use the `html()` helper function and pass the character reference:

```
gt() %>% 
  cols_label("Estimate" = "\U03B2")
```

or

```
gt() %>% 
  cols_label("Estimate" = "β")
```

or

```
gt() %>% 
  cols_label("Estimate" = html("&beta;"))
```